# Can I recover a single table from a SQL Server 2012 database backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have accidentally dropped a specific table and I don’t want to restore whole database (it is huge) but instead I want to recover only that table from a backup?

What would be most simplest solution?

Comment: You cannot really restore just a single table out of a SQL Server backup - SQL Server backups are all-or-nothing.

Comment: The Answer has not changed for a while.  You cannot restore a single table out of a backup.  Here is another (and the question that was original to the one vonPryz linked to.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4000/is-it-possible-to-backup-and-restore-part-of-a-database-in-sql-server

Comment: Red-gate makes an object level recovery tool which allows you to restore individual elements from a backup. http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-olr-native/

Comment: Reg gate is ok but not supporting SQL Server 2012